# How does NPM/Node.js do path resolution in the local node_modules/.bin directory

Tags: node.js, npm

Been confused about this for awhile

I have an executable file (cli/exec.js) in an NPM module called "foo" like so:

```
/foo
--/cli
   exec.js
--/lib
package.json
```

in package.json, we have:

```
  "name": "foo",
  "bin": {
    "exec-foo": "cli/exec.js"
  }
```

when this module gets installed, with npm install, node_modules looks like this:

```
--/node_modules
---/.bin
    exec-foo
---/foo
---/lodash
---/async
---/whatev
```

.........

...What confuses the crap out of me: how does Node.js do module/dependency resolution with the require function, now that the exec-foo.js file is no longer where it once was in the project, but is now located in `node_modules/.bin`? Is there a simple explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS resolution is pretty well explained in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module, and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then Node.js starts at the parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that location. Node will not append node_modules to a path already ending in node_modules.

In your case `node_modules/.bin/exec.js` will be a symbolic link - a pointer to the original file.

Then NodeJS checks the original file path and starts parsing the required modules. If it can't find in the current `node_modules` path goes 1 directory upwards until it finds your library.

If no library has been found it throws an error.

Comment: yep the key part is that the files in ./node_modules/.bin/* are symbolic links to files in ./node_modules/*